# How to calculate area of respective pixel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, arcmap, ndvi

I wants to create NDVI Map, In which it shows an area of respected pixel value lies in map.I have NDVI value within -0.6 to 0.7. Suppose,I wants to calculate area of 0.5 NDVI value with scale of map.How it can be done? How to convert pixel value into area value?

Answer (score 1):

You can usually assume that your pixels have the same area. This is exact for an equal area projection, and a approximation in case of other projection, so you need to be careful with this assumption if you work on large area. So what you need is count the number of pixels with a given value. With continuous values, however, counting is not directly possible. You therfore need to convert your values to integer ( int("ndvi" * 100)), then you can see the count in the attribute table.

Comment: I have attribution table new. later I wants to calculate area of same ndvi  in acres or in  hectares. further which steps will be  followed?

Comment: in the attribute table you have the count of pixels. You can find the size of your pixels in the general properties of your raster. So if you multiply the count by the area of the pixels, you have the area for each value.